# Android Studio editor not working for MainActivity

Tags: android, flutter

I'm working on a flutter project. I need to make changes to the MainActivity in the android folder. The the compile checking(if I write gibberish the editor doesn't give me any red lines)  is not working. Do I have to change a setting now that I'm working on a java file? Flutter doctor is fine.

Comment: Do you not get a 'Open for Editing in Android Studio' link in the top right corner, when viewing MainActivity's code? You might not have it anymore if you clicked on 'Hide' next to it - if that's the case I think you need to restart Android Studio first. When you open a Flutter project it doesn't include any of the Java stuff by default, as that requires inspecting, indexing, linting etc. of the entire Android API, as well as all the flutter plugins that have Java code, etc. which would make it very heavyweight when in reality you barely ever touch the Java code while working in Flutter.

Comment: What is the extension of MainActivity?

Comment: 'FlutterActivity' @RakshitNawani

Comment: @Ovidiu That ballon might have come up. But opening/closing AS doesn't make it reappear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hy,

you should open android folder on new window as a project in Android Studio,
to get the compiler works.

Comment: I'm platform channeling so would be nice to work in the same window

Comment: Here are some info about this https://flutter.dev/docs/development/tools/android-studio#android-ide

Comment: thanks, thats helpful. But the option  Flutter > Open Android module in Android Studio option........ is greyed out for me.

Comment: this is the solve of the disabled flutter > open Android module on your project: https://github.com/flutter/flutter-intellij/issues/3873#issuecomment-487397099

Comment: I hobe I could help you ✌